# How to turn 5 sets of data from one column into 5 different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My current table looks like this

| CPNT_ID | Org_Id | Stud ID | Compl_Dte |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trainee | Org001 | 101010 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| SvcTech | Org001 | 101010 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| CrewChief | Org001 | 101010 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| Trainee | Org001 | 101013 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| SvcTech | Org001 | 101013 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| Trainee | Org002 | 101011 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| SvcTech | Org002 | 101011 | Nov 13, 2016 |
| Trainee | Org002 | 101012 | Nov 13, 2016 |

This works if im looking at one organization, but if i need to see multiple organizations I need the table to look like this. I don't have enough reputation to chat

| Organization | Trainee | SvcTech | CrewChief | SvcCoord | Appr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Org001 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Org002 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This is my code

```
select 
cpnt.cpnt_id,
s.ORG_ID,
pc.stud_id,
pc.compl_dte
from 
        pa_stud_program sp,
        pa_program p,
        pa_student s,
        pa_stud_cpnt pc,
        ps_program_type pt,
        pa_cpnt cpnt
WHERE p.PROGRAM_SYS_GUID = sp.PROGRAM_SYS_GUID
    and pc.compl_dte is not null
    and cpnt.cpnt_id in ('Trainee','SvcTech','CrewChief','SvcCoord','Appr')
    and s.jp_id in ('1801','1805','1810','1811')
    and s.EMP_STAT_ID = 'Active'
    AND cpnt.CPNT_TYP_ID     = p.CPNT_TYP_ID
    AND cpnt.CPNT_ID         = p.CPNT_ID
    AND cpnt.REV_DTE         = p.REV_DTE
    AND pc.STUD_ID           = sp.STUD_ID
    AND sp.stud_id           = s.STUD_ID
    AND pc.CPNT_ID           = sp.CPNT_ID
    AND pc.CPNT_TYP_ID       = sp.CPNT_TYP_ID
    AND pc.REV_DTE           = sp.REV_DTE
    AND pc.seq_num           = sp.seq_num
    AND pt.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID   = p.PROGRAM_TYPE   
    /** and s.PERSON_ID_EXTERNAL  in [UserSearch]*/
```

Comment: Littlefoot if you see this I couldnt get org to fit into the other query so I rewrote it in hopes you can make it fit into this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case when to pivot the table,and group by in outer layer.
SQL code is following:

```
select ORG_ID as Organization
,sum(case when cpnt_id = 'Trainee' then 1 else 0 end) as Trainee
,sum(case when cpnt_id = 'SvcTech' then 1 else 0 end) as SvcTech
,sum(case when cpnt_id = 'CrewChief' then 1 else 0 end) as CrewChief
,sum(case when cpnt_id = 'SvcCoord' then 1 else 0 end) as SvcCoord
,sum(case when cpnt_id = 'Appr' then 1 else 0 end) as Appr
        
from (
select 
cpnt.cpnt_id,
s.ORG_ID,
pc.stud_id,
pc.compl_dte
from 
        pa_stud_program sp,
        pa_program p,
        pa_student s,
        pa_stud_cpnt pc,
        ps_program_type pt,
        pa_cpnt cpnt
WHERE p.PROGRAM_SYS_GUID = sp.PROGRAM_SYS_GUID
    and pc.compl_dte is not null
    and cpnt.cpnt_id in ('Trainee','SvcTech','CrewChief','SvcCoord','Appr')
    and s.jp_id in ('1801','1805','1810','1811')
    and s.EMP_STAT_ID = 'Active'
    AND cpnt.CPNT_TYP_ID     = p.CPNT_TYP_ID
    AND cpnt.CPNT_ID         = p.CPNT_ID
    AND cpnt.REV_DTE         = p.REV_DTE
    AND pc.STUD_ID           = sp.STUD_ID
    AND sp.stud_id           = s.STUD_ID
    AND pc.CPNT_ID           = sp.CPNT_ID
    AND pc.CPNT_TYP_ID       = sp.CPNT_TYP_ID
    AND pc.REV_DTE           = sp.REV_DTE
    AND pc.seq_num           = sp.seq_num
    AND pt.PROGRAM_TYPE_ID   = p.PROGRAM_TYPE   
) as a

group by ORG_ID
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Any chance you know how I can get this to be a unique count. I had the solution working vertically from this thread but now I need it horizontally... that's what she said.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734574/how-to-subtract-two-specific-rows-and-create-custom-column-with-answer

Comment: I am afraid you need ask another question because I am kind of confused by these question.